# I'm talking about the truths for every human, hidden by some countries and that

Tags: relative-clauses, prepositional-phrases, commas, lists

I'm curious about the grammatical accuracy of the sentence below

- I'm talking about the truths for every human, hidden intentionally by some countries, about our future, and that we have to learn as soon as possible.

I definitely know that the sentence is not natural, unnecessarily long, and doesn't read well. Nevertheless, I would like to learn if it is grammatically and theoretically correct.

I can also write the same sentence like

- I'm talking about the truths that are for every human, are hidden intentionally by some countries, are about our future, and that we have to learn as soon as possible.

But I'm curious about the first one's accuracy.
I think the first one is correct because "for every human", "hidden intentionally by some countries", "about our future" and "that we have to learn as soon as possible" are listed with commas as they modify the same noun "the truths" in a row.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is, as you implied, hideously constructed, but does seem to be grammatically correct.

Removing some clauses, and a conjunction, we get:

"I'm talking about the truths for every human ... that we have to learn as soon as possible."

Answer (score 0):

> I'm talking about the truths for every human, hidden intentionally by some countries, about our future, and that we have to learn as soon as possible.

> I'm talking about the truths **that** (are for every human), (are hidden intentionally by some countries), (are about our future), and **that** (we have to learn as soon as possible).

Example 1 is fine.

In example 2, I have placed parentheses for those that are parallel.  As shown, there is a problem due to the duplicated **that**.  Deleting the 2nd **that** should make this example work though it will still be too wordy, as you have said.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. I would like to ask you if you are a native speaker of English, and please don't get offended, it's so important to me for this question.

Comment: Some of native speakers didn't my sentence and I didn't exactly get why. As far as I understood, they are not plesant that I listed "noun phrases" and "relative clauses" at the same time.

Comment: *"Some of native speakers didn't [understand] my sentence"*. It is fairly easy to construct sentences that are grammatically and semantically correct, and when analysed, make perfect sense, but are, at first, second, or even third, reading, incomprehensible.